# I'm getting 'undefined is not an object (near '...}).fs.writeFile(' when trying to download base64 image png in react native React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, react-native-fetch-blob

Here is my code:

```
    const saveImg = async (base64Img: string, success: Function, fail:Function) => {
        const isAndroid = Platform.OS === "android"
        const isIos = Platform.OS === 'ios'

        const dirs = isIos? RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath : RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath;
        const certificateTitle = 'certificate-'+((Math.random() * 10000000) | 0)
        const downloadDest = `${dirs}/${certificateTitle}.png`;
        const imageDatas = base64Img.split('data:image/png;base64,');
        const imageData = imageDatas[1];

        try{
            await RNFetchBlob.config({
                addAndroidDownloads:{
                    notification:true,
                    description:'certificate',
                    mime:'image/png',
                    title:certificateTitle +'.png',
                    path:downloadDest
                }
            }).fs.writeFile(downloadDest, imageData, 'base64')
            if (isAndroid) {
              } else {
                RNFetchBlob.ios.previewDocument(downloadDest);
              }
            success()
        }catch(error:any){
            console.log(error)
            fail()
        }
    }
```

I get this error:

```
undefined is not an object (near '...}).fs.writeFile(downloadD...')
at node_modules/react-native-webview/lib/WebView.android.js:207:16 in _this.onMessage
```

When I hit the download button and this runs I get the mentioned Error.
I use to get the download done with the below code modification, but I really need to show the download feedback from both android and IOS.

This works (but without notification)

```
await RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(downloadDest, imageData, 'base64')
```

I am using expo

Comment: `I get the mentioned Error` ,? You did not mention any error in your post. Please do.

Comment: Why using RNFetchBlob when retrieving base64 ?
You didn't call fetch you just define a request object.

```javascript
RNFetchBlob.config({}).fetch("GET", "test.com", {
  })
```

Comment: @MichaelBahl I just need to convert the base64 string to image, download it and get the download manager notification, what's the best alternative ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the react-fetch-blob does not work with expo, to solve it, I used the following  libraries:

```
expo-file-system, expo-media-library, expo-image-picker,expo-notifications
```

This was the code to convert,  download and show the notification of the image in the "expo way":

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';

const saveImg = async (base64Img: string, success: Function, fail:Function) => {

    const imageDatas = base64Img.split('data:image/png;base64,');
    const imageData = imageDatas[1];

      try {
        const certificateName = 'certificate-'+((Math.random() * 10000000) | 0) + ".png"
        const certificatePathInFileSystem = FileSystem.documentDirectory +certificateName ;
        await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(certificatePathInFileSystem, imageData, {
          encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
        });
        await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(certificatePathInFileSystem);

        Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
            handleNotification: async () => ({
              shouldShowAlert: true,
              shouldPlaySound: false,
              shouldSetBadge: true,

            }),
          });

        await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
            content: {
                title: certificateName +' saved !',
                body: "Click to show the certificate",
            },
            trigger: null,
          });
          setCertificatePath(certificatePathInFileSystem)
      success()
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      fail()
      }
}
```

In order to open the images gallery on click I used this code:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if(certificatePath){
        Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener( async (event )=> {
            await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
                allowsEditing: true,
              })
        })
    }
},[certificatePath])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to call fetch after create RNFetchBlob.config
2. If you just wanna display an Image and not store you can show image as fallows (https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/images#uri-data-images)

```js
<Image
  style={{
    width: 51,
    height: 51,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  }}
  source={{
    uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
  }}
/>
```

Call fetch on config object:

```js
        try{
            const fetchConfig = await RNFetchBlob.config({
                addAndroidDownloads:{
                    notification:true,
                    description:'certificate',
                    mime:'image/png',
                    title:certificateTitle +'.png',
                    path:downloadDest
                }
            })
    fetchConfig.fetch('your.domain.com').fs.writeFile(downloadDest, imageData, 'base64')
            if (isAndroid) {
              } else {
                RNFetchBlob.ios.previewDocument(downloadDest);
              }
            success()
        }catch(error:any){
            console.log(error)
            fail()
        }
```